# why my lync server "cannot locate Central Management Store in AD"?

Tags: active-directory, lync-2013

I want to set up an environment for Lync Server 2013. And I walked along the tutorials as http://windowspbx.blogspot.hk/2012/07/step-by-step-installing-lync-server.html and http://prajwaldesai.com/step-by-step-installation-of-lync-server-2013-standard-edition-part-3-installing-lync-server-2013/ . I new 3 virtual machines for which I set static IP addresses: one is for lync server 2013, one is for AD DS/DNS/etc, one is for sql server 2012. After all the things involved in those two articles were done, I pulished the server. Here it gose: Failure! I tried and tried in different ways and looked up many other articles, however, the results point to one spot: cannot find location of Central Management Store in Active Directory. Oh I am going to be crazy! what should i do to fix it?
Any comment will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there may be many possible reasons for it. as for my situation, what i did to managed to figure it out is expanding space of disk. AD server and Lync server requires sufficient disk space for their running. usually you have to assign each of them more that 70G space.